# Xamarin Forms Animations on startup

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms

Im trying to get an image to be animated the moment the page is loaded but my approach doesnt seem to work on startup. But i have tested it with a button and it plays the animation no bother.

This is my constructor for my MainPage

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CreatePanel();

    var storyboard = new Animation();

    var enterTop = new Animation
    (
        callback: d => bannerIcon.TranslationY = d,
        start: -100,
        end: 0,
        easing: Easing.BounceOut
    );

    storyboard.Add(0, 1, enterTop);
    storyboard.Commit(bannerIcon, "Banner", length: 1000);

    Content = layout;
}
```

Should I have this code in the OnAppearing method or am I just coming at this completely wrong?

**SOLUTION**

Just had to move the animation code into the OnAppearing() method.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    banner.IsVisible = false;

    // animations
    menuAnimations.FlyIn(banner, 1000);

    menuAnimations.Rotate(btnSocial, 360);
    menuAnimations.Rotate(btnVideo, 360);
    menuAnimations.Rotate(btnSchedule, 360);
    menuAnimations.Rotate(btnLunchMenu, 360);
    menuAnimations.Rotate(btnContact, 360);
    menuAnimations.Rotate(btnDetails, 360);
}
```

Comment: This looks like Xamarin.iOS, not Forms.

Comment: No no its forms. Well Ive been using this code in my forms project and it works perfectly when attached to a button or whatnot. I just dont know how to have it play the animation on startup

Comment: Try putting it in the OnAppearing method instead of the constructor.

Comment: Ya that seemed to work. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Your running the animation before you Content is even set (Possible Animation is finished before you can even view it which help with argument of the animation working on button click I would also do as you suggested and move the animation.commit inside the OnAppearing method and set the animation to a longer length for testing purposes